# Google maps API watchPosition keeps adding new marker on each update of user's location

Tags: javascript, gps, maps

Trying to use a function which will track the user location in a Google MAP Javascript API. This code works as intended but it also adds a new marker for each GPS update. How do I keep one marker and have it update to the user's location?

```
        function getLocation1(){
             
   
            
    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        (position) => {
          const pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
          };
          
          
           var  lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lon = position.coords.longitude;


//const myLatLng = latlon ;


  const locs = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: lat, lng: lon },
    map,
    title: "",
  });
 
 
 
   if (locs  == null) {    
  locs.setMap(map);
   };
  
  locs.setPosition(pos)

  



//        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
//         infoWindow.setContent("You are here");
//         infoWindow.open(map);
          map.setCenter(pos);
          map.setZoom(17);
        },
        () => {
          handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      );
      
      
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - forgotten to globalize locs.